# Mercurial - How do I diff with a previous version?

Tags: mercurial

I'm using the command

```
hg kdiff3 filename
```

to visualize differences between my current status and what's pushed in the master repository.

If I was to see the differences between a specific revision (say 5 commits back) and the current, how would I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the changes between two versions of a file in the repository:

```
 hg kdiff3 -r 4 filename
```

where the current version is assumed to be the "other" changeset. If you want to compare two past revisions:

```
 hg log filename
 hg kdiff3 -r2 -r7 filename
```

where the revision numbers `-r2 -r7` are drawn from the changeset log.